# Max value in array. Why is the code not working?

Tags: arrays, max

I tried using an algorithm to find the highest number in an Int array. But the code seems not to be working probably and I don't know why. I wrote another code and the program works ok now ,but just want to find out why this particular code is not working properly. Thank you!

```html
public static int maxNumberOfPoints (int [] max){
  int maxPoints=0;
  for  (byte counter=1;counter<max.length;counter++){
   if(max[counter]>=max[counter-1]){
    maxPoints =(int) (max[counter]);   
   
   }
  }
  
  return maxPoints;
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are comparing to the former element on the list instead of comparing with  maxPoints. Here, try this:

```
public static int maxNumberOfPoints (int [] max){
    int maxPoints=0;
    for  (byte counter=0;counter<max.length;counter++){
        if(max[counter]>maxPoints{
            maxPoints =(int) (max[counter]);            

        }
    }

    return maxPoints;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only ever compare an element to the one before it; you should be comparing each against the biggest you have seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your comparison,

```
if(max[counter]>=max[counter-1])
```

You are looking to see if the current value in the array is greater than the one just before it.
Which means you will just get the last value where the previous one is greater.

What you want is to compare it to the maximum found so far (maxPoints)

```
 if(max[counter]>=maxPoints)
```

And also you will need to change your loop to start at `counter=0`

Answer (score 0):

Below should do the trick if you want find the minimum element in an array:

```
public static int maxNumberOfPoints (int [] max){
  int maxPoints=max[0];

   for  (byte counter=0;counter<max.length;counter++){
    if(max[counter]>maxPoints{
        maxPoints =(int) (max[counter]);            

    }
}

return maxPoints;
```

}

The slight change and a very important part of the algorithm is you have to find the maximum number in the given array. With your code, you assume the maximum is zero so your code will fail if you have an array of negative numbers.

If I have: int [] myArray = {-6,-2,-1,-5,-8}, your algorithm will return 0 which is not correct(should be -1).

So, by saying the first element is the maximum and you keep that minimum as you traverse the array and encounter an element bigger than your current maximum.